# Convert a tensorflow dataset to a python list with strings

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Consider the following code below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

simple_data_samples = np.array([
         [1, 1, 1, -1, -1],
         [2, 2, 2, -2, -2],
         [3, 3, 3, -3, -3],
         [4, 4, 4, -4, -4],
         [5, 5, 5, -5, -5],
         [6, 6, 6, -6, -6],
         [7, 7, 7, -7, -7],
         [8, 8, 8, -8, -8],
         [9, 9, 9, -9, -9],
         [10, 10, 10, -10, -10],
         [11, 11, 11, -11, -11],
         [12, 12, 12, -12, -12],
])

def timeseries_dataset_multistep_combined(features, label_slice, input_sequence_length, output_sequence_length, batch_size):
    feature_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(features, None, input_sequence_length + output_sequence_length, batch_size=batch_size)

    def split_feature_label(x):
        x=tf.strings.as_string(x)

        return x[:, :input_sequence_length, :], x[:, input_sequence_length:, label_slice]

    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(split_feature_label)

    return feature_ds

ds = timeseries_dataset_multistep_combined(simple_data_samples, slice(None, None, None), input_sequence_length=4, output_sequence_length=2,
batch_size=1)
def print_dataset(ds):
    for inputs, targets in ds:
        print("---Batch---")
        print("Feature:", inputs.numpy())
        print("Label:", targets.numpy())
        print("")



print_dataset(ds)
```

The tensorflow dataset "ds" consists of an input and target.
Now I would like to transform the tensorflow dataset to a python list with the following properties:

```
Index Type Size  Value 
0     str    13   1  2  3  4      5  6 
1     str    13   1  2  3  4      5  6
2     str    13   1  2  3  4      5  6
3     str    13   -1 -2 -3 -4    -5 -6   
4     str    13   -1 -2 -3 -4    -5 -6
5     str    13    2  3  4  5     6  7
.... and so on
```

In the above example, we hypothetically created a python list containing strings. In the field "value" you can see the inputs of the tensorflow datasets on the left hand side (e.g. 1 2 3 4 with an whitespace between the strings) and on the right hand side you can see the corresponding targets (e.g. 5 6 with a whitespace between the strings). It is important to note that there is a horizontal tab "\t" between the inputs and targets (e.g. 1 2 3 4.\t5 6.)

How would I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `pandas` dataframe, you could try something like this:

```
features = np.concatenate(list(ds.map(lambda x, y: tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(x, axis=0)))))
targets = np.concatenate(list(ds.map(lambda x, y: tf.transpose(tf.squeeze(y, axis=0)))))

values = list(map(lambda x: x[0]+ "\t" + x[1], zip([" ".join(item) for item in features.astype(str)], 
                                                   [" ".join(item) for item in targets.astype(str)])))
types = [type(v).__name__ for v in values]
sizes = [len(v) for v in values]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Size':sizes, 'Type':types, 'Value':values})
df.index.name = 'Index'
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your print_dataset function.

```
def print_dataset(ds):

    list_sets = []

    for input, targets in ds:

        input = np.transpose(np.array(inputs)[0])
        label = np.transpose(np.array(targets)[0])

        for input_set, label_set in zip(input, label):

            set = ""
            set = "".join(str(value).replace("b'", "").replace("'", "") + " " for value in input_set)

            set += "\t" # add the tab

            set += "".join(str(value).replace("b'", "").replace("'", "") + " " for value in label_set)
            set = set[:-1] # remove the trailing white space

            # print(set) #prints each line individually 
            list_sets.append(set)

    print(list_sets) # prints the whole list
```

Ignore that you can see the "\t" instead of a tab with spaces if you print the individual lines every works fine. Python only prints the "\t" to shorten the length by replacing useless space with shortcuts.

Comment: ever heard of a simply `return list_sets ` ?